# Error with a vector when I did permutation

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to permutate my numbers in the vector.

Below are my codes. This code is very simple. Firstly, the input size of a vector is determined by user-input. And then, all the numbers in the vector are permutated in order to find the maximum integer value and minimum integer value when I concatenated all the numbers into one string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string retS(const vector<int>& v)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int e : v) {
        s += to_string(e);
    }
    return s;
}


int main(void) {
    int num = 0;

    cin >> num;

    vector<int> numbers;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    unsigned long long maxVal = 0;
    unsigned long long minVal = 987654321;
    do {
        string s = retS(numbers);
        if (stoll(s) > maxVal) {
            maxVal = stoi(s);
        }


        if (stoll(s) < minVal)
            minVal = stoi(s);

    } while (std::next_permutation(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()));

    cout << maxVal+minVal << endl;
}
```

However, the problem is that the error occurred when I inputted two digit numbers. For example, I inputted `10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 20` into my vectors, then my codes didn't work. I think it is because the range of integer variable because the concatenated string can be a size of 20(~up to 20) if I assume only one or two digit number can be accepted.
Therefore, I changed my integer variable into `unsigned long long` type from `int`, which is, i think, the longest range value for storing integer type, but, the program was aborted when I executed.

So, Can you help me to have this code work well?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expected output will be the maximum value + minimum value from all the permutated numbers and concatenated them.

Comment: @Anders K. expected output is dependent on the inputted values. for example, I inputted 1,2,3, then the maxVal will be `321` and minVal will be `123`. but the problem is the case of two digit values.

Comment: Number `90807060504030202010` is greater than `2^64` sou you are out of bounds of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Zereges, so is it impossible to store such a value into long type variables?

Comment: It is impossible to store it in `unsigned long long`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zereges noted the problem here is that you are trying to store a number that exceeds the capacity of the biggest numeric variable type that C++ has built-in. You can solve this problem storing such long numbers as strings. This will solve the problem you have, but it will make your code a bit slower.

If you don't want to fight with strings more than necessary this could help you: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/  It's a library to work with big integers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I have made a mistake in my post.

***---The Begining of the Mistake---***

Firstly, below statement perhaps may not function as you expect.

```
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), sort() sorts the elements in the range [first,last) into ascending order. In fact, there is the same problem for `std::next_permutation()`.

There indeed is a difference between parentheses and square brackets. `[` means `>=` while `)` means `<`. According to your code, the last element would not be sorted.

***---The End of the Mistake---***

*I have just discovered that `end()` does not return an iterator referring to the last element in the vector container, but the past-the-end element, which is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the vector.*

Moreover, I see you have declared two `unsigned long long` to hold the values.

```
unsigned long long maxVal = 0;
unsigned long long minVal = 987654321;
```

It seems that `987654321` is the upper limit of the value you would like to store. However, there are few potential problems in your code which may make the value's upper bound fails.

(1) The upper limit is not applied to `maxVal`.

```
if (stoll(s) > maxVal) { //may add a upper boundary for maxVal
    maxVal = stoi(s);
}
```

(2) The functions of `stoll()` and `stoi()` returns a `long long` and an `int` respectively. In case, a number greater than the upper limit of `long long` and `int` is caught, the above 2 functions will throw `std::out_of_range` exception. This is a restriction in using the functions. It seems this was the run-time error you have encountered. In addition, though you have tried to declare `unsigned long long` to store the values, it does not release the restriction in using the 2 functions.

To fix it, you may try the suggestion from Carlos.

Below is a possible implementation of the suggestion from Carlos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string retS(const vector<int>& v)
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        s += to_string(v.at(i));
    }
    return s;
}

//prone to error
bool str1GreaterThanStr2(const string str1, const string str2)
{
    if (str1.size() != str2.size())
        return (str1.size() > str2.size());

    int cursor = 0;
    while (cursor < str1.size())
    {
        if (str1.at(cursor) != str2.at(cursor))
            return (str1.at(cursor) > str2.at(cursor));
        cursor++;
    }

    return false; //if both string are the same
}

int main(void) {
    int num;
    vector<int> numbers;

    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    string maxStr = retS(numbers);
    string minStr = retS(numbers);

    while (std::next_permutation(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()))
    {
        string str = retS(numbers);
        maxStr = str1GreaterThanStr2(str, maxStr) ? str : maxStr;
        minStr = str1GreaterThanStr2(str, minStr) ? minStr : str;
    } 

    cout << maxStr << endl;
    cout << minStr << endl;
}


/*
test case tried:
10
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 20
*/
```

Hope this helps.